# How to correctly use get_template_directory_uri() WordPress function to load an image that is in a subfolder of my theme?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new in WordPress and I have the following doubt about how to insert in my homepage an immage that is in a subfolder into my theme directory.

So I have the following situation: Into my custom theme directory I have the following folder that contains a jpg immage: **/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg**

Now in my **header.php** file I have something like this:

```
   <li>
       <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg">
       <div class="flex-caption">
           <p class="flex-caption-text">
               <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
               <span>sit dolor</span><br>
               <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
           </p>
       </div>
   </li>
```

Obviously, when I load the page, the immage **flex-1.jpg** is not loaded because there is not the right path (infact using FireBug I obtain that it try to load the **assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg** immage) so I think that I could use the absolute path but this is pretty orrible !!!

So I am thinking to use the **get_template_directory_uri()** function provided from WP to do this and I have try to change the previous code in this way:

```
   <li>
       <img src=<?php get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg' ?>>
       <div class="flex-caption">
           <p class="flex-caption-text">
               <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
               <span>sit dolor</span><br>
               <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
           </p>
       </div>
```

But don't work and using **FireBug** I can see that load nothing, infact in my brower source code I have:

```
<img src="">
```

Why don't work? What am I missing?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hope it will work:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg" />
```

If your assets folder inside theme.

Comment: +1 - it's kind of a nit picky point, but echo is more consistent with WordPress coding standards than print()

Answer (score 2):

please try :

```
<img src="<?php print(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg" />
```

just check for slash, if double before "assests", remove static one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/yourimage.jpg">
```